# not-null constraint violated for default value column when importing csv via psql

Tags: postgresql, csv, psql

I'm using a command `my $cmd = "/usr/bin/psql -h $host -d $dbname -p $port -U $user -c \"\\\\COPY ${shema_name}.$table_name FROM '$csvFile' WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER '$delimiter' \";";` for importing csv file to Postgres DB.
The command is then executed by Perl code:

```
my ($stdout, $stderr) = capture {system ($runCmd)};
```

Table definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE schema.table (
col1 varchar(50) NOT NULL,
col2 timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Csv file:

```
col1;col2
0023124;
```

Import of csv seems to be working without using column col2, or if it's containing some values. But when there are no values in the col2 it fails with error message `null value in column "col2" of relation "table" violates not-null constraint` even though there is DEFAULT value defined. In case I remove col2 from csv it return error `missing data for column col2`

Does anybody know, how to import csv to Postgres table so that defaul value current_timestamp will be used for col2?

Comment: 1) From here [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html): *NULL Specifies the string that represents a null value. The default is \N (backslash-N) in text format, and an unquoted empty string in CSV format. ...*. 2) So you are providing a value of `NULL` which means the `DEFAULT` will not be used. 3) You have two choices provide a reasonable value in the CSV file or remove the `NOT NULL` constraint on the column for the import.

Comment: thanks @AdrianKlaver for the explanation, it helped

Answer (score 0):

You have to use PostgreSQL v16 or better. Then you can

```
COPY tab FROM STDIN (
   FORMAT 'csv',
   HEADER,
   DELIMITER ';',
   DEFAULT '',
   NULL 'some nonsensical stuff that doesn''t occur'
);
```

Before v16, which introduced `DEFAULT`, I don't think that you can achieve your goal with `COPY`.